# Puppeteer on Elementary OS

Tags: release-loki

I am attempting to use [reveal-md](https://github.com/webpro/reveal-md) to generate slide decks using markdown files. I followed the instructions to install reveal-md using npm `npm install -g reveal-md`.

One of the optional dependencies is puppeteer, which is a library that interfaces with Chrome/Chromium API's, and allows the user to print a slide deck to PDF.

reveal-md was installed successfully, but I get this error for puppeteer in my terminal:

```
ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r549031! Set 
"PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 
'/usr/lib/node_modules/reveal-md/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium'
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/reveal-md/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium' }
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 
(node_modules/reveal-md/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: puppeteer@1.3.0 (node_modules/reveal-md/node_modules/puppeteer):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: puppeteer@1.3.0 install: `node install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

When I installed puppeteer manually via `npm install -g puppeteer`, I get a similar error:

```
ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r588429! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
{ Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium'
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@1.8.0 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@1.8.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-09-13T00_07_56_867Z-debug.log
```

I even tried promoting myself to the root user and attempting the install command, but I received the same error.

I did a web search for "npm install puppeteer error," and I have seen several comments that this is probably an issue with npm permission. Is there a way I can fix this manually?

**UPDATE 9/14/18:**

The answer by @rmmcneely, below, is correct to fix my specific error. As a more permanent solution, I followed [npm's instructions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) for changing the global prefix, in the config file, to point to a location I created in my home folder `~/.npm-global`, which solves any permission issues with global packages.

#### Option 2

1. Back-up your computer before you start.
2. Make a directory for global installations: `mkdir ~/.npm-global`
3. Configure npm to use the new directory path: `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`
4. Open or create a `~/.profile` file and add this line: `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`
5. Back on the command line, update your system variables: `source ~/.profile`
6. Test: Download a package globally without using `sudo`. `npm install -g jshint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EACCES indicates a permission error generally, double check who owns your global node_modules folder in /usr/lib and try to either install with those permissions, or chown the dir.

Comment: Thanks @rmmcneely! I ended up changing my npm prefix to my home folder `~/.npm-global`, following the instructions in [npm's documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).